# Set timezone according to different country locale wise in php

Tags: php, timezone

I have set one default timezone in PHP. And the datetime field data inserted according to that. But now I want to convert that field value according to different country timezone wise when I display it. So is it possible?

For example:

I have set default timezone 'Asia/Kolkata'
and in database insert record according to this time but now when any user from USA also got the same time when he show any record inserted.

But I need he will get his time means I need to convert Asia/Kolkota to 'America/Phonix' timezone when site access from USA

Comment: share some code here

Comment: use date_default_timezone_set :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Check the gmdate methods, this is not going to be fun.